# Ext JS items config

Tags: javascript, extjs

the generic Ext JS application created using the ext code generator tool, there are a lot of arrays named "items". I can tell this is a configuration of some sort which can contain objects of key/value pairs but I cannot find any detailed documentation on this specifically. there are certain keys in the key/value pairs, such as xtype, reference, listeners, etc., is there an exhaustive list of such keys that can be used in a items array? What is this thing called in Ext JS lingo, items config? I did find mention of the "items config" on the Layouts and Containers page of the 6.7.0 documentation, but unfortunately it was a broken link and just basically mentioned it but gave no details.

example from the application:

```
items: [
    { xtype: 'navview',    reference: 'navview',    docked: 'left',   bind: {width:  '{navview_width}'}, listeners: { select: "onMenuViewSelectionChange"} },
    { xtype: 'headerview', reference: 'headerview', docked: 'top',    bind: {height: '{headerview_height}'} },
    { xtype: 'footerview', reference: 'footerview', docked: 'bottom', bind: {height: '{footerview_height}'} },
    { xtype: 'centerview', reference: 'centerview' },
    { xtype: 'detailview', reference: 'detailview', docked: 'right',  bind: {width:  '{detailview_width}'}  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `items` configuration is available for all ExtJS components that are descendants of the [Ext.container.Container](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.container.Container.html) class. As you can see from the [items](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#cfg-items) config description:

> A single item, or an array of child Components to be added to this
>   container

The main config from the items object is [xtype](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-xtype). This is basically an alias of the component's class.

> This property provides a shorter alternative to creating objects than
>   using a full class name. Using xtype is the most common way to define
>   component instances, especially in a container.

You can check [Ext.enums.Widget](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.enums.Widget.html) for a full list of xtypes that ExtJS provides.
Alongside `xtype` you can have any other config properties [available](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#configs) for the component that `xtype` determines.

You can also usually define custom xtypes for your own component classes, and the use them in your `items` config. As there seems to be the case in the code you've provided. Those are not predefined ExtJS xtypes.